# How to append data to an existing shared preference file

Tags: android

If I have a shred preference file called "myshared" how I can append data to it not overwrite ?

[image]

I need to make a registration system and I want to save each new user data (username and password) using sharedprefernces not external files my problem with each new user data always myshared.xml is overwritten 
I've answered my post :

I've tried to solve this by creating a new xml file each time with different Id this is my

Edit My Post :

```
package com.example.task_8;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Ac_3 extends Activity {

    Button save;
    EditText userName,password;
    String name,pass,oldUser,oldpass,oldId;
    Intent i;



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        setContentView(R.layout.ac_3);

        save= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);



        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

          i = getIntent();




            TextWatcher listener = new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    name= userName.getText().toString();
                    pass= password.getText().toString();




                    } 


            };

            password.addTextChangedListener(listener);
            userName.addTextChangedListener(listener);




            save.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    File f=new File("/data/data/com.example.task_8/shared_prefs/"+name+".xml");

                    if(f.exists())

                            {


                        AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
                        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Ac_3.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("error msg");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("This user name already exist , try another one");
                        alertDialog.show();



                            }

                    else 

                    {

                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("myshared"+name, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
                        spe.putString("userName",name);
                        spe.putString("password",pass);
                        spe.commit();

                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);


                    }


                }

            });

}

}
```

Comment: can you clarify your intent?

Comment: I need to make a registration system and I want to save each new user data (username and password) using sharedprefernces not external files my problem with each new user data always myshared.xml is overwritten :(

Comment: so multiple user can register an account on the same device?

Comment: there is an activity called registration has 2 edit texts userName and password AND when the user finish typing data and press save button the data should be stored in a shared preference

Comment: Shared preferences is used for simple data and new data is override if the same id. In your case if you want to save older logins you should use sqlite for this

Comment: imho you should use a contentprovider

Comment: my task is to use shared preference not other method I hope to use sqllit :(

Comment: If you have to use shared preferences, you have to create various id for login1, 2, 3 and pass and check if in your code for then

Comment: @ blackbelt: Ok what is this ?? I'm beginner

Comment: @nininho: give me an example please , I'm confused :\\

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the SharedPreferences documentation and I found one option for you.

You can have a `Set<String>` added to preferences using [getStringSet()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29), so you would have to save a set of usernames and passwords to the SharedPreferences, so you can have a history of logins.

EDIT:
Since you are creating a preference for each user, then before saving to the preference file you get the username for the preference file, so if the username is not null, then you already have the preference file and the user is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate file with name as user-name, allowing you to store more info about each user:

creation:

```
    String userName = "user_1";
    String password = "passwd";

    String hash = doHashPassword(password);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(userName,MODE_PRIVATE);
    sp.edit().putString("pass",hash).commit();
```

authorization:

```
    String userName = "user_1";
    String password = "passwd";

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(userName,MODE_PRIVATE);
    String hash = sp.getString("pass",null);

    if(hash != null && hash.equals(doHashPassword(password))){
        //--login success
    }else {
        //--access denied
    }
```

SQLite is another good option.